# Can an iOS device be secure while being Jailbroken?

Tags: ios, security, encryption

In researching how iOS devices (iPhone/iPad/iPodTouch) are protected via encrypted I came across many articles that mentioned if a device was "jailbroken" then the built in encryption of the iOS device was essential null and void. That by jailbreaking, the default encryption could be bypassed.

Assuming this is true is there anyway to enable the encryption features of an iOS device while maintaining a Jailbreak? There are a lot of tweaks I really make use of a lot (SBSettings) and I would hate to have to give them up in order to maintain security on iOS.

Comment: Yes and no. A reckless person may install software that makes the lock screen and other security features vulnerable to attacks by opening holes in the system, but other software may actually improve security (by changing the SSH/root password and such). But I haven't jailbroken in a long time, so I'm not sure. (Obviously, security is voided if you install trojan spyware, but everybody knows that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jailbreaking removes the requirement for apps to be digitally signed. Anything will run now - so yeah you need to be careful what you load on there.

It's not an encryption issue thou.

Comment: That makes sense. The software I was referring to described itself as something that was loaded as a RAMDisk at the iPhone bootup and that without being jailbroken it would not be allowed to run. So the fact that the Jailbroken iPhone allows "unsigned" apps to run ends up allowing this "forensic" app to execute. Sure would be nice if there was an option to allow/disallow unsigned apps to run on a per app basis.

Comment: Sure but the only way additional unsigned apps are going to get on your device in the first place is if you install them. Why would you do that and then not want them to run?

Comment: My concern would be if anyone ever got hold of my device. Then they would be able to install the program themselves. Of course if my iOS was NOT jailbroken it would not matter so much as the attacker could just jailbreak the device themselves. I was hoping to use the iPad as a diary/journal platform but unfortunately it is not secure enough .. at least for my taste.